# Postgresql 9.2.1, vacuum freeze process stuck while running

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-performance

In postgresql 9.2.1, database avoid accepting commands to prevent wraparound dataloss issue.I was running **vacuum freeze verbose** process in single user mode in the respective database. Suddenly, the vacuuming process got stuck in the half way through (just frozen while vacuuming some transactions) with the warning message,

**WARNING: database "XXXX" must be vacuumed within 997218 transactions. 
HINT: To avoid a database shutdown, execute a full-database VACUUM in "XXXX".**

- What would be the reasons for that vacuuming process can stuck in
  half way ?
- How can i prevent it ?

Please help me.

Comment: Didn't you post about this before? I seem to remember pointing out that 9.2.1 is ancient, and the first thing you should do is update to the latest 9.2 since it incorporates many bug fixes, and it's possible some are relevant.

Comment: Yes. But at first, i tried **vacuum full** command in single user mode. Then, i was instructed to execute **vacuum freeze**. I got stuck while trying vacuum freeze operation. And i couldn't update the postgres version until this issue will be resolved, right ?  Because i can't made any further transaction in pgsql normal mode.

Comment: Wrong, you can, and should, update the postgres binaries to the latest 9.2.x version.

Comment: Note that if you have the free space, you SHOULD take a binary backup of the db while it's shut down.